# ordenar consulta por 2 fechas de distintas columas como si fuera una sola fecha

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, postgresql

realize una union de 2 tablas, cada tabla tiene fecha y hora pero el nombre de sus columnas y el contenido de cada una es distinto, por lo que en mi consulta requiero ordenar toda la consulta desde la fecha mas actual a la mas vieja utilizando  ambas fechas, si utilizo un order by fecha_readquisicion; se ordenaran por el primer select y para el caso de fecha_canalizacion; se ordenara por el 2do select. Lo que quiero es que se orden utilizando las fechas de ambas columnas, gracias.

```
select id_canalizacion,null as id_readquisicion,fecha_canalizacion,hora_canalizacion, null as fecha_readquisicion, null as hora_readquisicion,
            canalizacionesprodutsa.id_solicitud,COALESCE(estado,'CANALIZADO')estado,solicitudesprodutsa.id_expediente,clave,propietario,fraccionamiento,manzana,lote 
            from canalizacionesprodutsa JOIN solicitudesprodutsa ON canalizacionesprodutsa.id_solicitud = solicitudesprodutsa.id_solicitud JOIN expedientesprodutsa ON solicitudesprodutsa.id_expediente = expedientesprodutsa.id_expediente
            where canalizacionesprodutsa.id_solicitud =192 
            union 
select null,id_readquisicion,null,null,fecha_readquisicion,hora_readquisicion,
            readquisicionesprodutsa.id_solicitud,COALESCE(estado,'READQUIRIDO')estado,solicitudesprodutsa.id_expediente,clave,propietario,fraccionamiento,manzana,lote 
            from readquisicionesprodutsa JOIN solicitudesprodutsa ON readquisicionesprodutsa.id_solicitud = solicitudesprodutsa.id_solicitud JOIN expedientesprodutsa ON solicitudesprodutsa.id_expediente = expedientesprodutsa.id_expediente
            where readquisicionesprodutsa.id_solicitud =192
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una opción sería `ORDER BY COALESCE(fecha_canalizacion,fecha_readquisicion),COALESCE(hora_canalizacion,hora_readquisicion)` (Con `ASC` o `DESC` si lo necesitaras)

Comment: En cualquier caso, para uniones como la tuya  en que tienes la columna diferenciadora de `estado` para indicar el origen de cada registro, yo en general prefiero tener una sola columna de `fecha` porque lo demás se entiende que viene de `estado`, y además así la ordenación sería más sencilla. Pero bueno... eso ya depende de gustos y también a veces de necesidades/libertades

Comment: @VFG Muchas gracias , funciono a la perfeccion!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrias hacer es mezclar ambas columnas en una sola, y al final ordenar usando esa columna,
en el ejemplo abajo, al final de tu lista de campos agregué las fechas en una columna (fechaorden)

```
select ..., fecha_canalizacion fechaorden
from canalizacionesprodutsa ...
where ...
union 
select ...,fecha_readquisicion fechaorden
from readquisicionesprodutsa ... 
where ...
order by fechaorden
```